How many distinct trees graphs can be made with $5$ vertices (hence $4$ edges)?
I tried finding the number of chained ones I can make, so $$4! + (4!-3!) + (4!-2 \times 3!) + (4!-3 \times 3!) + (0) = 60,$$
then I found the number of ones where one of the vertex would have $3$ edges going into it ${4 \choose 3} \times 5 = 20$,
then $4$ edges in each vertex, which is a star tree graph, and there is only $5$, which accounts for $85$ of the tree graphs.
How do I find the other $40$, and which ones am I missing?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are your vertices labelled? I think so, but I would like to still clarify it.

It looks like you are talking about labeled trees.
Also I suppose that by "chained ones" you mean path graphs. I don't understand your the method of computation without some clarification, but I can verify that the answer is correct. Every vertex permutation gives us a labeled path graph, and every labeled path graph corresponds to exactly $2$ permutations, up to selection of the first and the last vertices. So there are $5!/2 = 120 / 2 = 60$ labeled path graphs on $5$ vertices.
The number $5$ of star graphs is correct, too. But the number of labeled trees with one vertex of degree $3$ is wrong. Indeed, if there is a vertex $v$ of degree $3$, there are at least $3$ leaves, so degree of the remaining vertex $u$ is $(5 - 1) \cdot 2 - 3 - 1 \cdot 3 = 2$. There are $5$ ways to label the vertex $v$, and $4$ ways to label the vertex $u$. One leaf is adjacent to vertex $u$, and two leaves are adjacent to vertex $v$, therefore there are $3$ ways to label leaves. It gives $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 60$ ways to label the tree on $5$ vertices with a vertex of degree $3$.
